# Python issue with saving with html ellipsis char

Tags: python, lxml, python-3.4, openpyxl, ellipsis

I'm opening a xlsx file that has strings similar to this:

`Some text ......`

When I pull that data using Openpyxl and save it out as an xml file using lxml, I get the ellipsis code `&#8230;`

I want it to preserve the ... and not convert it to `&#8230;` - Wondering what the best way to handle this would be.

This issue does not exist using python 2.7, I'm converting scripts to python 3.4 which is where I see the issue.

Code example. I created a xlsx file with test in first row/column like this.

`test data ......`

The following code pulls that data and when it saves it out I get the ellipsis instead in the xml

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from lxml import etree

workbook = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
test_data = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value

root = etree.Element("root")
ele = etree.SubElement(root, 'test_data')
ele.text = test_data

et = etree.ElementTree(root)
et.write('test.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

xml results

```
<root>
  <test_data>test data&#8230;&#8230;&#8230;.</test_data>
</root>
```

Fixed issue in the write

```
xml.write(path, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of code to reproduce this? (assuming we have created an excel file with the `...` character-- the MS Office apps tend do make that conversion without asking so should be easy to create the input file).

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with openpyxl which just returns the data stored by Excel, which in this case is the ellipsis character. However, what gets printed in Python may depend upon your encoding.